# How do I create centroids inside polygons in Python?

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, centroids

When creating centroids from polygons, ArcMap has an option to placing the centroids inside (within the bounds of) the polygons. I am attempting to create centroids in Python. I have tried:

```
df['geometry'].centroids
```

The problem is that some polygons are shaped *crescent-like*, or *doughnuts* as in the shown example so the resulting centroids are outside the polygons.
Is there a way of making the centroids fall inside their polygons in Python?

[image: Output from df.geometry.centroids method]

Using the function below suggested by @ThomasG77 does produce a good result.

```
df['geometry'].representative_point()
```

[image: Output from representatitive_points() method]

However, is there a way to influence the placement of this point so that it falls as centrally as possible within the bounds of the shape?

Answer (score 7):

You just need to use the method `representative_point` that borrows the shapely method (shapely library borrows the method from GEOS library PointOnSurface method e.g https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/0ecc21c0aaef478dbfdc55bcf3b6e90a039e4b64/shapely/geos.py#L631)

So reusing your example you should use `df['geometry'].representative_point()`